# Jquery animated sortable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i have 2 lists which contain some items that must be draggable from the left one to the right, and sortable in the right. i've struggled to add animation to the lists which i dont know how it works. but if you drag an item from the right and into the left list, and slowly drag it out without dropping, it will not come out of the left list (sortable2).
and the other issue is that i dont know why the placeholder is larger than the original item and why does it have a shadow?
here is my code:
[My fiddle (working)](https://jsfiddle.net/tp93f9d6/)
****UPDATE:just figured out that removing the margin from *li* can fix the bug but now i need to fix the items in the middle. any ideas?

```js
$(function() {
        $( "#sortable1 li" ).draggable({
   cursor:"move", cursorAt:{top:50, left:40},
            connectToSortable: ".connectedSortable",
            helper:"clone",
   revert:150,
            remove: function(event, ui) {
                ui.item.clone().appendTo('#sortable2');
                $(this).draggable('cancel');
            }
        }).disableSelection();
    
 
 
 
 
 
    $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
  axis:"y",
  placeholder: "slide-placeholder",
     start:function(e,ui){
        
        placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
        ui.placeholder.height(placeholderHeight + 15);
        $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);
    
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        
        ui.placeholder.stop().height(0).animate({
            height: ui.item.outerHeight() + 15
        }, 300);
        
        placeholderAnimatorHeight = parseInt($(".slide-placeholder-animator").attr("data-height"));
        
        $(".slide-placeholder-animator").stop().height(placeholderAnimatorHeight + 15).animate({
            height: 0
        }, 300, function() {
            $(this).remove();
            placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
            $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);
        });
        
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        
        $(".slide-placeholder-animator").remove();
        
    },
        }).disableSelection();
    });
```

```css
#sortable1 { list-style-type: none; margin: auto; padding: 0; float: right; }
    #sortable2 { list-style-type: none; margin: auto; padding: 0; float: left; min-height:130px; width:130px; border:1px solid black; }
    #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {  padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; line-height:100px; width: 70px; height: 100px; border-radius:10%; color:#ffffff; box-shadow:3px 3px 1px #888888; }
    .red{background-color:#ff3300;}
    .blue{background-color:#1111ff;}
    .black{background-color:#000000;}
    .green{background-color:#00fd01;}
    .yellow{background-color:#ffff66;}
    .slide-placeholder{height:100px; background-color:#DADADA; border:1px dotted red;  -webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
   <ul id="sortable1">
    <li class="ui-state-default red">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default blue">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default black">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default green">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default yellow">Item 5</li>
   </ul>

   <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">

   </ul>



 </body>
```

Comment: i get the error: `Object doesn't support property or method 'draggable'`.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes i see that too cant figure out the reason the code works on my PC i will try and fix it asap

Comment: @NinaScholz i've added my fiddle link doesnt work as it should but the bug is there

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution for the second half of the question https://jsfiddle.net/3tdtkcu4/

```js
$(function() {
  $( "#sortable1 li" ).draggable({
    cursor:"move", 
    cursorAt:{top:50, left:40},
    connectToSortable: ".connectedSortable",
    helper:"clone",
    revert:150,
    remove: function(event, ui) {
      ui.item.clone().appendTo('#sortable2');
      $(this).draggable('cancel');
    }
  }).disableSelection();
   
  $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
  axis:"y",
  placeholder: "slide-placeholder",
    start:function(e,ui){
      placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
      ui.placeholder.height(placeholderHeight - 10);
      $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);
    
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
      ui.placeholder.stop().height(0).animate({
        height: ui.item.outerHeight() - 10
      }, 300);
        
      placeholderAnimatorHeight = parseInt($(".slide-placeholder-animator").attr("data-height"));
        
      $(".slide-placeholder-animator").stop().height(placeholderAnimatorHeight - 15).animate({
        height: 0
      }, 300, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
        $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);
      });   
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      $(".slide-placeholder-animator").remove();  
    },
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable1 { 
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: auto; 
  padding: 0; 
  float: right; 
}

#sortable2 { 
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: auto; 
  padding: 0; 
  float: left; 
  min-height:130px; 
  width:130px; 
  border:1px solid black;
}
    
.ui-state-default { 
  margin: 10px 29px; 
  padding: 5px; 
  font-size: 1.2em; 
  line-height:100px; 
  width: 70px; 
  height: 100px; 
  border-radius:10%;
  color:#ffffff; 
  box-shadow:3px 3px 1px #888888;
}
    
.red {
  background-color:#ff3300;
}
    
.blue {
  background-color:#1111ff;
}

.black {
  background-color:#000000;
}

.green { 
  background-color:#00fd01;
}

.yellow { 
  background-color:#ffff66;
}

.slide-placeholder {
  margin: 10px 29px; 
  padding: 5px; 
  font-size: 1.2em; 
  line-height:100px; 
  width: 70px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:10%; 
  background-color:#DADADA;
  border:1px dotted red; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: none; 
  -moz-box-shadow: none; 
  box-shadow: none; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable1">
  <li class="ui-state-default red">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default blue">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default black">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default green">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default yellow">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">

</ul>
```

Hope this will help you.
Can you explain the 1st half of the problem.

Comment: sure do this to see the problem: drag an item from sortable1 to sortable2 and don't drop it. slowly drag the item to the borders of draggable 2 and try to pull it out slowly. you will see that the item and the cursor will start jumping and item won't come out of the list.